# python re.search invalid expression even though it works on PHP and various other regex matchers

Tags: regex

date = re.search(r'([\x\d\w-.\s,()&\"]+|)

I am migrating a code from PHP to Python, and am using this piece of regex expression on re.match, which doesn't work, giving a python error of:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
```

It works on PHP's preg_match, and also http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr , any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting `\x` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\x
```

on its own is invalid (both in PHP and Python, but perhaps PHP just ignores it while Python throws an exception). Try removing it, and also moving the `-` to the end of the character class:

```
date = re.search(r'<td>([\d\w.\s,()&\"-]+|)<br><font',page_data)
```

But in all cases, you won't get very happy if you try parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: RE: Parsing X?HTML with regexes: [DON'T DO IT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).